# creating database from sql command line and using it in Java jdbc code

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to create my database using pure sql code from sql command line [sql command line image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0m9iK.png)and   want to connect to the database from java code(jdbc). 
But while doing so I am facing problems- here is what I have tried:
I have set the path of the driver - ["**mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin**"-a jar file ]-  in path variable as well as ,on some suggestions from internet, I added this jar file to the [**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\jre\bin**] folder. but  when I run my program from command prompt it shows an Exception - the image - [message from command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAyRO.png). I have created a user  for the databse  from sql command prompt too. 
here is my java code -

```
  import java.sql.*;

  public class JDBCDemo
{
  public static void main(String... args)
 {
   try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/studentdb?useSSL=false","amir","amir5");
    // step 2 . allocate a statement object in the connection 

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    )   {
       //step 3. execute  a SQL select query, the query result 
         String strSelect = "select * from student;";
         System.out.println("The sql query is "+ strSelect);
         System.out.println();
         ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(strSelect);
         System.out.println("the records are selected");
         int rowCount =0;
         while(rset.next())
         {
             String name = rset.getString("name");
             String roll = rset.getString("roll_num");
             int id = rset.getInt("id");
             System.out.println(name+", "+roll+", "+id);
             ++rowCount;
         }
         System.out.println(rowCount);
        }
         catch(SQLException e)
         {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 

   }    
}
```

how can I get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not look here and there! just set up your mysql command line and install netbeans . netbeans has inbuilt Drivers. create a database in mysql command line  then create a project in netbeans and double click on the library folder and select add library, a screen will pop up , scroll down it and select mysql odbc driver and you are done!!write your code and execute queries.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`

Refer tutorial [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database)

Note: Download the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjava5123binjar.htm). It is not mentioned in that tutorial. Then set the class path where you download it.

```
import java.sql.*;  
class MysqlCon{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonoo","root","root");  

//here sonoo is database name, root is username and password  

Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  

ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");  

while(rs.next())  
System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getString(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3));  

con.close();  

}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  

}  
}
```

Comment: it doesn't work- command prompt message -                                                 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Comment: @Amir Hasan : Have you referred the tutorial as i mentioned?

Comment: yes, I did.  I had copied the tutorial in fact the database name too.

Comment: Download the jar file here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmysqlconnectorjava5123binjar.htm. Then set the class path as mentioned in the tutorial and try it.

Comment: @Amir Hasan : Are you using Windows or Linux OS?

Comment: 1. I have downloaded the jar file . 2. ihave pated the jar file in jdk->jre->lib->exe-> folder.  3. I am have downliaded the sql server from - mysql.com -"mysql-installer-web-community-5.7.13.0" 4. I have installed it. 5. I am having it set up. still cmd says  no suitable driver found.. please help me .. I have wasted my 35+ hours for  establishing the database connection .. I am exhausted now..

Comment: I just followed the tutorial and it works fine for me. (1) Download mysql-connector.jar and paste it in jre/lib/ext folder. (2) Download mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar.zip it in downloads folder and extract it and set the classpath -> <Your download path>/mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar. (3) javac MysqlCon.java (4) java MysqlCon.

Comment: please tell me the steps in the form of an algorithm,if possible. right from •installing mysql (mention the link , where to download from , if possible), to •writing jdbc program. that may help me understand where I have been doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Given the error message

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql//localhost:3306/studentdb?useSSL=false
```

your connection string is missing the colon after "mysql". It should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost ...
```

Comment: please tell me the steps in the form of an algorithm,if possible. right from •installing mysql (mention the link , where to download from , if possible), to •writing jdbc program. that may help me understand where I have been doing wrong!!

Answer (score 0):

Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/studentdb","amir","amir5");

use this line it will work perfectly

Comment: please tell me the steps in the form of an algorithm,if possible. right from •installing mysql (mention the link , where to download from , if possible), to •writing jdbc program. that may help me understand where I have been doing wrong!!